# ¿ Como crear una lista desordenada con punto al comenzar cada linea nueva?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Hola estoy creando un documento y alguna sección quiero que sea como muestro abajo, una lista de varios párrafos, los cuales tengan tabulación respecto al resto del texto de la pagina dejando espacio a la izquierda en todos el párrafo de la lista y su punto al inicio de cada párrafo nuevo.

Como Esto es lo que necesito:
`

- Un párrafo con tabulacion y punto al inicio donde escribir lo que mi lista necesita
- Aqui lo consigo con una simple lista, pero en mi proyecto no funciona.

Aquí funciona, pero en mi proyecto no aparecen ni el Punto, ni la tabulación en los párrafos de la lista.
Muestro una captura de lo que sale en mi pagina:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el proyecto estoy usando Bootstrap v3.3. y  Font Awesome 4.4.0, no se si esto tendrá algo que ver pues en mi pagina se muestra sin la tabulación ni el punto al inicio, simplemente se muestran dos párrafos.
Muestro el código que empleo para la lista:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
   Un párrafo con tabulacion y punto al inicio donde escribir lo que mi lista necesita
  </li>
   <li>
Aqui lo consigo con una simple lista, pero en mi proyecto no funciona.
  </li>
</ul>
```

¿ Que debo hacer para conseguir lo que necesito ?

Gracias.

Comment: Probablemente alguna de los dos librerías te esté pisando el css que hace que se vean los puntos.

Comment: Como dice **@ Iñigo Irigoyen Erquicia** es muy posible que una de las librerías te esté pisando los CSS. Para ver si es esto lo que está ocurriendo podrías inspeccionar el elemento en cuestión desde el navegador y ver si existe alguna regla CSS que le esté poniendo **list-style-type: none**. También podrías si no forzarlo tú desde el CSS de tu proyecto usando un **list-style-type: circle**. También podrías no cargar momentaneamente dichas librerías para ver si se te sigue produciendo el problema y así descartar que sea culpa de estas.

Comment: Como dijeron los demás: `list-style-type: disc;` Prueba también `list-style-type: bullet;`

Comment: Gracias a todos por el apoyo. He provado el ejemplo de @Macaroni, pero falta el detalle de la tabulacion de los parrafos ¿ como se corrige eso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto sucede porque has aplicado un estilo CSS y tu archivo CSS está sobrescribiendo los estilos del navegador. Para añadir este estilo a una lista, simplemente tienes que añadir lo siguiente en tu selector CSS:

```
list-style-type: disc
```

Recuerda que el uso de !important está desaconsejado. Si la lista no te coge el estilo, deberías ser más específico con el selector para evitar el uso de !important. Por ejemplo, poniendo un atributo de clase a tu elemento unordered list y otro atributo de clase a los elementos list item.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    /*Así identamos toda la lista*/
    ul.listaEjemplo{
      margin-left:40px;
    }
    
    ul.listaEjemplo li.itemEjemplo {
    list-style-type: disc;
    text-indent: 10px;
    }
    ul.listaEjemplo li.itemEjemploIdentado {
    list-style-type: disc;
    text-indent: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="listaEjemplo">
    <li class="itemEjemplo">
      Un párrafo con tabulacion y punto al inicio donde escribir lo que mi lista necesita
    </li>
    <li class="itemEjemplo">
      Aqui lo consigo con una simple lista, pero en mi proyecto no funciona.
    </li>
    <li class="itemEjemploIdentado">
      Item con identación grande.
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="listaSinIdentar">
    <li class="itemEjemplo">
      Un párrafo con tabulacion y punto al inicio donde escribir lo que mi lista necesita
    </li>
    <li class="itemEjemplo">
      Aqui lo consigo con una simple lista, pero en mi proyecto no funciona.
    </li>
    <li class="itemEjemploIdentado">
      Item con identación grande.
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias @Macaroni he provado tu ejemplo y funciona sin estropear otras listas, pero falta el detalla de la tabulacion. Los parrafos de la lista no hacen tabulacion

Comment: Perdona, no leí bien tu pregunta. Para eso sólo tienes que aplicar margin left (en caso de querer identar todo el item) o text ident (en caso de querer separar el texto del punto). Te lo añado al ejemplo.

Comment: Exacto, como te he comentado, para identar todo el párrafo debes usar margin left. Está en el fiddle de ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias, llevaba todo el día detrás de ello. Perdona por no haber visto lo del margin-lef

Answer (score 1):

Como ha dicho **@Iñigo Irigoyen Erquicia**, tiene pinta de que las librerías están sobreescribiendo el código css una de otra.

En algún punto, una de las librerías está borrando los puntos predefinidos de las listas de `html`. La forma de arreglarlo sería machacar estos estilos desde tu css para devolverlos. Para ello debes usar la propiedad `list-style` sobre la lista.

```css
ul {
  list-style: disc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
   Un párrafo con tabulacion y punto al inicio donde escribir lo que mi lista necesita
  </li>
   <li>
Aqui lo consigo con una simple lista, pero en mi proyecto no funciona.
  </li>
</ul>
```

El valor predeterminado que coge es `disc` pero puedes ver [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp) los diferentes valores que puedes darle por si prefieres cambiar su estilo.

Si siguiera sin funcionar posiblemente fuera porque el estilo de las librerías sigue por encima del tuyo, eso podría solucionarse añadiendo `!important` a tu propiedad para indicarle que su prioridad es mayor:

```
ul {
    list-style: disc!important;
}
```

Comment: El uso de important está desaconsejado por considerarse una mala práctica. En vez de eso tendría que hacer un selector más específico, como ya he comentado en mi respuesta. Esta no es una buena solución.

Comment: No puedo saber si la lista es algo que puede generar con código a mano siempre o es algo que pueda llegarle dinámico en algún punto. Aunque sea una mala práctica, algunas veces no podrás hacer un selector más específico sin crear código redundante, habría que tener en cuenta todas las posibilidades. En un caso en el que quieres el mismo estilo en todas las listas de la aplicación (tengas control o no sobre ellas), personalmente no lo veo mala práctica

Comment: En el caso de que las listas vinieran de un servicio o algo parecido, lo que dices está bien, pero a en el código que él está mostrando las listas están en el documento HTML, por lo tanto lo que dices no se ajusta a su ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias @Rabegi lo solucione con lo que propuso Macaroni, igualmente se agradece el apoyo.